# Как автоматически перезапускать плейбук?

Tags: bash, ansible, devops

Конфигурация проходит через VPN и возникают периодические отваливания в соединении, что приводит к остановке плейбука для данного хоста.

Если в самом Ansible инструмент, перезапускающий плейбук до тех пор, пока .retry не останется пустым?

Пока вижу выход в небольшом баш скрипте с `whle true` циклом.

Answer (score 3):

Подобных средств на уровне плейбука не знаю, а бесконечный while это откровенный костыль.

Вам могут помочь следующие вещи:

- включите [pipelining](https://habrahabr.ru/company/d2cio/blog/343368/) в скриптах ansible чтобы увеличить скорость выполнения скрипта
- увеличьте [таймаут ssh на своём сервере](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25084288/5752652)
- включите в конфиге [retries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40340761/5752652)
- если вышеперечисленное не помогло, то подумайте о режиме ansible-pull (выполнять скрипты локально на самом сервере)

Также можно подумать о том, чтобы каждый шаг плейбука [переписать в стиле](https://coderwall.com/p/ww4dxw/ansible-retry-task):

```
---
- hosts: all
  connection: local
  tasks:
      - shell: exit 1
        register: task_result
        until: task_result.rc == 0
        retries: 10
        delay: 1
        ignore_errors: yes
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, все из перечисленного уже опробывалось.
pipelining не поддерживает become_method = su, поднимал вопрос на GitHub
https://github.com/ansible/ansible/issues/35698

retries = 2,3 не дает абсолютно никакого эффекта в моем случае.

Comment: @Hellseher Очень жаль, что вы сразу это не упомянули в вопросе.

Comment: @Hellseher и даже ansible-pull не работает?

Comment: @NickVolynkin. конфигурируются железные сервера с доступом в один конец через vpn